# Can't load file in ExtJS if running locally

Tags: javascript, extjs

I was running a simple Tree example on my webstorm. In my **Index.html** I had this code which accessed a **treegrid.json** file in the same folder.

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: 'Task',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            //the store will get the content from the .json file
            url: 'treegrid.json'
        },
        folderSort: true
    });
```

I want to be able to have it running just from the file system. So I double clicked the index.html from explorer, but I got this error :

> file:///C:/developer/eclipse/workspaces/iLean/JS_FrameworkTest/Extjs/test/t…B%22property%22%3A%22leaf%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D&node=root.
>   Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

So I decided to put in the full file path, to see if that did anything :

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model: 'Task',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            //the store will get the content from the .json file
            url: 'C:\\developer\\eclipse\\workspaces\\iLean\\JS_FrameworkTest\\Extjs\\test\\treegrid.json'
        },
        folderSort: true
    });
```

But this gives the same error.

I am assuming that the **proxy --> type : ajax** setting is wrong. I would assume that there was something like **type : filesystem**, but I can't find any documentation on the ExtJS site.

Comment: You need to run it through a webserver.

Comment: yes, but is it possible to run it through the file system? I want to have a clickable demo where its just local.

Comment: Use a local web server dude really, plus right click ie and delete it :P

Comment: Are you using `Cmd` to build your project? Simply running `sencha app watch` will deploy a basic http-server locally while you're testing.

Comment: not using server. just plugging in some components in my app